# I have created a navbar in HTML and CSS which contains a dropdown menu, but at the same time header also expands

Tags: html, css

When I click on the dropdown menu, it shows the corresponding menu, but also the header expands at the same time. This I don't want.

Comment: can you please add your code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fix the issue when you haven't included the code, but just off the top of my head I'd say give the navbar a fixed defined height (eg 100px) then set overflow to visible. That should fix it.

Comment: Actually the code I have written is too long to be added into the comment. This is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Thank you for the little advice which you gave me.